# jQuery UI slider handle left position range limitation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, position

I am trying to set the left position on the jQuery UI slider handle to start at 5% and max out at 95%. I want to limit the range of the left position. Is there anyway to have this type of offest and have it constant and not reset to 0%-100% ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

JS

```
$j("#ageRangeSlider").slider({
          range: "min",
          value: 11,
          min: 11,
          max: 66,
          step: 11,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
            $j("#yourAgeRange").val(ui.value);
            foo = $j("#yourAgeRange").val();
          }
        });
        $j("#yourAgeRange").val($j("#ageRangeSlider").slider("value"));
```

HTML that jQuery UI creates

```
<div id="ageRangeSlider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false">
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-slider-range-min" style="width: 0%;"></div>
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>
```